# Cannot run spark decision tree on rapidminer process

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, rapidminer

I'm working on windows 8.1, Hadoop 2.6, spark 1.6, hive and rapidminer 9.0 version.
I have a process composed by these operators: retrieve data from hive, set role, spark decision tree.
radoop is configured and i can access to hive data.
when I run the process the spark decision tree operator last much time to run without no result.
on yarn namenode ui web show that the spark job is failed and in rapidminer I have this error :

```
Please verify your Spark Resource Allocation settings on the Advanced Connection Properties window. You can check the logs of the Spark job on the ResourceManager web interface  at http://${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8088.
```

in yarn ressource manager logs i have these notifications:

```
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
18/11/07 10:43:50 INFO scheduler.AppSchedulingInfo: Application application_1541
582549574_0006 requests cleared
18/11/07 10:43:50 INFO rmapp.RMAppImpl: application_1541582549574_0006 State cha
nge from FINAL_SAVING to FAILED
18/11/07 10:43:50 INFO capacity.LeafQueue: Application removed - appId: applicat
ion_1541582549574_0006 user: user queue: default #user-pending-applications: 0 #
user-active-applications: 0 #queue-pending-applications: 0 #queue-active-applica
tions: 0
18/11/07 10:43:50 WARN resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=user OPERATION=Applic
ation Finished - Failed TARGET=RMAppManager     RESULT=FAILURE  DESCRIPTION=App
failed with state: FAILED       PERMISSIONS=Application application_154158254957
4_0006 failed 1 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1541582549574_0006_0000
01 exited with  exitCode: 1
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://asus:8088/proxy
/application_1541582549574_0006/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1541582549574_0006_01_000001
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:
715)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.la
unchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.C
ontainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.C
ontainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Shell output:         1 fichier(s) déplacé(s).


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.  APPID=application_1541582549574_
0006
18/11/07 10:43:50 INFO capacity.ParentQueue: Application removed - appId: applic
ation_1541582549574_0006 user: user leaf-queue of parent: root #applications: 0
18/11/07 10:43:50 INFO resourcemanager.RMAppManager$ApplicationSummary: appId=ap
plication_1541582549574_0006,name=Decision Tree,user=user,queue=default,state=FA
ILED,trackingUrl=http://asus:8088/cluster/app/application_1541582549574_0006,app
MasterHost=N/A,startTime=1541583816334,finishTime=1541583830966,finalStatus=FAIL
ED
```

This is the XML process description

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="9.0.003">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="9.0.003" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="radoop:radoop_nest" compatibility="9.0.002" expanded="true" height="103" name="Radoop Nest" width="90" x="179" y="85">
        <parameter key="connection" value="hadoop"/>
        <parameter key="change_sample_size" value="true"/>
        <enumeration key="tables_to_reload"/>
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="radoop:retrieve" compatibility="9.0.002" expanded="true" height="68" name="Retrieve (2)" width="90" x="45" y="340">
            <parameter key="table" value="forum"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="radoop:set_role" compatibility="9.0.002" expanded="true" height="82" name="Set Role" width="90" x="179" y="340">
            <parameter key="name" value="categforum"/>
            <parameter key="target_role" value="label"/>
            <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="radoop:decision_tree_ml" compatibility="9.0.002" expanded="true" height="82" name="Decision Tree" width="90" x="313" y="340">
            <parameter key="file_format" value="PARQUET"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="radoop:apply_prediction" compatibility="9.0.002" expanded="true" height="82" name="Apply Model" width="90" x="447" y="340">
            <list key="application_parameters"/>
          </operator>
          <connect from_op="Retrieve (2)" from_port="output" to_op="Set Role" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Set Role" from_port="example set output" to_op="Decision Tree" to_port="training set"/>
          <connect from_op="Decision Tree" from_port="model" to_op="Apply Model" to_port="model"/>
          <connect from_op="Decision Tree" from_port="exampleSet" to_op="Apply Model" to_port="unlabelled data"/>
          <connect from_op="Apply Model" from_port="labelled data" to_port="output 1"/>
          <connect from_op="Apply Model" from_port="model" to_port="output 2"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_output 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_output 2" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_output 3" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Radoop Nest" from_port="output 1" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

when I try to test only spark on rapidminer I have this error results:

```
SEVERE: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
SEVERE: Timeout on the Spark test job. Please verify your Spark Resource Allocation settings on the Advanced Connection Properties window. You can check the logs of the Spark job on the ResourceManager web interface at http://localhost:8088.
SEVERE: Test failed: Spark job
SEVERE: Integration test for 'hadoop' failed.
```

Comment: Can you perhaps share your RapidMiner process setup? Also did you try to execute the Spark decision tree outside the "Radoop Nest" operator?

Comment: of course, the process is into the radoop Nest

Comment: The error message is quite generic. Could you check if the Radoop full test runs through? If so, can you check the underlying logs, for example like this:    "yarn logs --applicationId <appId>"

Comment: how can I check yarn logs? what should I type in the prompt? I'm sorry for that question because I'm new with Hadoop. I edited the question added the result of the test spark on rapidminer.

Comment: Maybe it's a question of time execution of job spark because I have "java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException " when I run test spark ! what do you think?